# Streaming video from ip webcam via opencv and python on raspberry

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to display video stream through an IP webcam.

```
import cv2
import sys
cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.43.1:8080/video')
while True:
# Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = video_capture.read()

  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.2,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
  )

# Draw a rectangle around the faces
  for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
      cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Display the resulting frame
  cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break
# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code runs perfectly fine on the PC but when I run it on Raspberry it shows the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3737
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_vid_detect.py", line 26, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Instead of editing the question it would have been better if it was answered.

Answer (score 1):

This error means there is an empty frame and you cannot convert an empty frame to gray.
So the your webcam is not able to start.
Look for a proper way to run a webcam in Raspberry Pi.
In general if you add
cv2.VideoCapture(0) in the beginning,
by default it should take your webcam as capturing device.